# Help installing ethzasl_icp_mapper in Indigo

Tags: ros, ethzasl-icp-mapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody help me installing this package in Indigo? I do not know how to do it, since it last realease was for hydro.

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236187/help-installing-ethzasl_icp_mapper-in-indigo/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on 2016-06-09**:
Hello,
I am having the same problem. Any ideas? Even wild guesses are welcome :)

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-16**:
did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, to compile the "ethzasl_icp_mapping" library in "ROS indigo" under "Ubuntu 14.04"

it is necessary do the following in catkin_ws / src :

```
1- git clone -b indigo_devel https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping.git
2- git clone -b release/indigo/libnabo https://github.com/ethz-asl/libnabo-release.git
3- git clone -b release/indigo/libpointmatcher https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher-release.git
```

4- in catkin_ws execute: catkin_make_isolated

5- in catkin_ws / devel_isolated execute:  source setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) with karma: 76 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-17**:
is there any alternative to make it work without isolation? I am not used to work with that.
Or could you tell me where is a tutorial or something like that to set my mind in order?
Thanks for your answer!!!